# Flutter Error "Could not navigate to inital root in my app"

Tags: flutter

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 2,632ms.
I/flutter (17581): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (17581): The following message was thrown:
I/flutter (17581): Could not navigate to initial route.
I/flutter (17581): The requested route name was: "/home"
I/flutter (17581): There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be
I/flutter (17581): ignored and "/" will be used instead.
I/flutter (17581): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I just want to override the '/' route for now, '/home' need this to be my first screen that message appear. some help me, I'm the new guy to flutter

My code here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/choose_location.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:worldtime/pages/loading.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/home',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => Loading(),
    'home': (context) => Home(),
    '/location': (context) => ChooseLocation()
  },
));
```

Comment: Please add your main.dart code in which you specified the routes

Comment: You mis-typed the home route, you need to write /home or else set your initialRoute as home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-typed the route. You have written route as:

```
'home': (context) => Home(),
```

You need to change that to:

```
'/home': (context) => Home(),
```

Comment: It'll work even without adding the forward-slash also right? It's just a convention of writing route names? @MidhunMP

Comment: @VinothVino Yes, forward slash is not mandatory. If you won't specify the initial route it will try to use `/` route by default. In that case if you don't specify such a route there will be a problem.

Comment: If I use the home property of Scaffold instead of providing the initial route. It'll work, right? Then what is the difference? As per my knowledge, we can provide named route as a string in the initialRoute property but in the home, we'll return a widget. @MidhunMP

Comment: @VinothVino Yes, you are correct. Both will work. Usually if you have only a page in your app use home property, else use routes.